# Do dictionary attacks only use specific entries from a dictionary, or combinations of an entry?

Tags: passwords, attacks

If I wanted to crack a password, "cba", but the dictionary I was using only had abc in it, does a dictionary attack try all combinations of abc? abc, acb, bca, bac, cba, cab

Or would cba have to be specified in the dictionary in order to try it?

Comment: Understand what you're asking. Would be interesting to hear what the applications of such a recovery approach is. And since you mention dictionary: are   a b c   really characters or do they represent words?

Answer (score 1):

The most powerful feature of oclHashcat is the rule based attack. The rule engine can accept characters to rotate the passwords in the list, so using the '{' character in the rule file will rotate the word left by one char. 'abc' will become 'bca', then 'cab'. You can also reverse the word using 'r', 'abc' will become 'cba', then rotate left or right if you wish. This barely scratches the surface. Check:

https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=rule_based_attack

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  Most password cracking tools (oclHashcat, John the Ripper, etc.) support some kind of password "mangling".  The most common types of changes will be things like CaSe VarIaTion, l33tsp34k, appending1 numbers2014, and the other kind of changes people commonly make to their passwords.  So, given input like 'password', it might try 'p4ssw0rd', 'P4$$w0rd!', 'passw0rD1', etc.  I'm not aware of common variations of ordering, but it probably exists.